# Crystal Sub-report in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

Below code is for main report and sub-Report. main report is working fine but 
when i add sub-report code it throws an exception message: "Missing Parameter Values".But i put all the parameters correctly.

```
    string strSelect = "";
    strSelect = "SELECT * FROM Daily_Order WHERE orderDate BETWEEN '" + txtDateFrom.Text + "' AND '" + txtDateTo.Text + "' and catagory='" + ddlCategory.SelectedItem.Text + "'   ";

    ReportDocument report= new ReportDocument();
    ds = dataProvider.getDataSet(strSelect, "Daily_Order");
    report.Load(Server.MapPath("Report\\Challan.rpt"));
    report.FileName = Server.MapPath("Report\\Challan.rpt");
    report.Refresh();
    report.SetDataSource(ds);

    report.SetParameterValue("Combined", 10);
    report.SetParameterValue("Suppliment1", 10);
    report.SetParameterValue("CombinedMax", 10);
    report.SetParameterValue("individual", 10);
    report.SetParameterValue("individualMax", 10);
    report.SetParameterValue("SupplimetMax1", 10);
    report.SetParameterValue("Suppliment2", 10);
    report.SetParameterValue("SupplimentMax2", 10);
    report.SetParameterValue("SupplimentPage2", 10);

    report.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "erp", "accpac-dbserver", "ALOCIR");
```

// Sub-report starts here

```
   ReportDocument Subreport = report.Subreports[0];

    string strSubSelect = "Select * from Daily_Order where orderDate between '" + txtDateFrom.Text + "' and '" + txtDateTo.Text + "' and catagory='" + ddlCategory.SelectedItem.Text + "' ";
    ds1 = dataProvider.getDataSet(strSubSelect, "Daily_Order");
    report.Load(Server.MapPath("Report\\Challan.rpt"));
    report.OpenSubreport("summary").SetDataSource(ds1.Tables[0]);

    report.SetParameterValue("ExtraDhk", 10, "summary");
    report.SetParameterValue("ExtraCtg", 10, "summary");
    report.SetParameterValue("ExtraBog", 10, "summary");
    report.SetParameterValue("Combined", 10, "summary");
    report.SetParameterValue("individual", 10, "summary");
    report.SetParameterValue("CombinedMax", 10, "summary");
    report.SetParameterValue("individualMax", 10, "summary");

    report.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "erp", "accpac-dbserver", "ALOCIR");
    Subreport.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "erp", "accpac-dbserver", "ALOCIR");

    report.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Server.MapPath("Report/Challan.pdf"));
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page.GetType(), "popupOpener", "var popup=window.open('Report/Challan.pdf');popup.focus();", true);
```

### Exception throws on that line:

```
 report.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Server.MapPath("Report/Challan.pdf"));
```

Did i miss any line of code? wont't find any solution- please help

Comment: Do your sub report contains any parameters ?

Comment: yes, it contains 7 parameters @abdul

Answer (score 0):

SET sub report parameters like this

```
 report.Subreports[0].SetParameterValue("@your parameter name", parameter-value);
```

Comment: throws expection: "Not supported within subreports"-@Abdul

Comment: **throws exception "Not supported within subreports" on that line:**  'report.Subreports[0].SetParameterValue("@ExtraDhk", 10);' @Abdul